# Sum of list numbers smaller than one goal

Tags: combinatorics

I have five values ​​that I would like to add them so that they can be equal to or less than 3000.

```
v1 = 140; v2 = 280; v3 = 420; v4 = 560; v5 = 700; goal = 3000;
Subsets [{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}]
```

For example:

```
v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1
```

-> 2940

```
v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v2
```

-> 2940

```
v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v3
```

-> 2940

```
v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v4
```

-> 2940

```
v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v5
```

-> 2940

```
v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v2 + v2
```

-> 2940

```
v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v1 + v2 + v2 + v2
```

-> 2940

All are possibilities, among other possibilities.

Is there a feature that validates these possibilities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Append `1` to the list of `v`s and use [`FrobeniusSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html):

```
w = {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, 1};
res = FrobeniusSolve[w, 3000][[2;;, ;; 5]];
Length[res]
```

> 1345

```
Short @ res
```

> {{0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,2},{0,0,0,0,3},{0,0,0,0,4},{0,0,0,1,0},<<1336>>,{19,0,0,0,0},{19,1,0,0,0},{20,0,0,0,0},{21,0,0,0,0}}

```
And @@ Thread[Total /@ res <= 3000]
```

> True

Up to ordering, `res` is the same as Henrik's `resulttable`:

```
Sort[res] == Sort[resulttable]
```

> True

An alternative way to use `IntegerPartitions` using `w`:

```
res2 = DeleteCases[Rest@IntegerPartitions[3000, All, w], 1, 2];
Length@res2
```

> 1345

```
restab = Map[Lookup[Counts[#], Most @ w, 0] &] @ res2;
Sort[res] == Sort[restab]
```

> True

To get the totals that can be obtained using `v`s:

```
Sort[DeleteDuplicates[res.Most[w]]] (* or *)
Sort[3000 - DeleteDuplicates@Rest[FrobeniusSolve[w, 3000]][[All, -1]]]
```

> {140, 280, 420, 560, 700, 840, 980, 1120, 1260, 1400, 1540, 1680,
>   1820, 1960, 2100, 2240, 2380, 2520, 2660, 2800, 2940}

```
Sort @ Counts[res.Most[w]]
```

> <|140 -> 1, 280 -> 2, 420 -> 3, 560 -> 5, 700 -> 7, 840 -> 10, 
>    980 -> 13, 1120 -> 18, 1260 -> 23, 1400 -> 30, 1540 -> 37, 
>    1680 -> 47, 1820 -> 57, 1960 -> 70, 2100 -> 84, 2240 -> 101, 
>    2380 -> 119, 2520 -> 141, 2660 -> 164, 2800 -> 192, 2940 -> 221|>

**Update:** You can also use `Reduce` and `Solve`:

```
v = {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5};
xv = Array[x, 5];
resReduce = Reduce[{v.xv <= 3000, ##&@@Thread[xv >= 0]}, xv, Integers][[2;;, All, -1]] /.
  {And | Or -> List}; 
resSolve = xv /. Rest@Solve[{v.xv <= 3000, ## & @@ Thread[xv >= 0]}, xv, Integers];
res == resReduce == resSolve
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

```
a = {140, 280, 420, 560, 700};
results = Join @@ DeleteCases[
     IntegerPartitions[#, {1, ∞}, a] & /@ Range[3000],
     {}
     ];
And @@ Thread[Total /@ results <= 3000]
resulttable = Map[Lookup[Counts[#], a, 0] &, results];
resulttable // Short
```

> True
>
> {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, <<1341>> , {19, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {21, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

Answer (score 3):

```
v1 = 140; v2 = 280; v3 = 420; v4 = 560; v5 = 700; goal = 3000;
Select[Subsets[{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}], Total[#] <= goal &]
```

Are you sure your "goal" is 3000?  Every subset totals less than that.

And what does `21 * v1` in your question refer to?  What is $21$, and why multiplication?

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {140, 280, 420, 560, 700};
coef = Tuples[Range[0, 21], 5];
vec = coef.a;

Extract[coef, Position[Ramp[vec - 3000], 0]] // Short
```

> {{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,2},{0,0,0,0,3},{0,0,0,0,4},{0,0,0,1,0},<<1335>>,{18,1,0,0,0},{19,0,0,0,0},{19,1,0,0,0},{20,0,0,0,0},{21,0,0,0,0}}

```
Pick[vec, Ramp[vec - 3000], 0] // Short
```

> {0,700,1400,2100,2800,560,1260,1960,2660,1120,1820,2520,1680,2380,<<1318>>,2940,2800,2380,2940,2800,2660,2940,2520,2940,2800,2660,2940,2800,2940}

Answer (score 3):

Could use integer linear programming via `Maximize`, for example. The constraint I use is overkill, all we really need to enforce is that values be nonnegative.

```
vals = {140, 280, 420, 560, 700};
goal = 3000;
vars = Array[v, Length[vals]];
Maximize[{vars.vals, 
  Flatten[{vars.vals <= goal, 
    MapIndexed[0 <= # <= Floor[goal/vals[[#2[[1]]]]] &, 
     vars]}]}, vars, Integers]

(* Out[1287]= {2940, {v[1] -> 10, v[2] -> 4, v[3] -> 1,
    v[4] -> 0, v[5] -> 0}} *)
```